# URL to soundcloud artist id

Tags: soundcloud

Given a link such as: `https://soundcloud.com/glennon-williams/spacedude`

What's the easiest way to get the user's id? Right now I parse the user's name so I get: `glennon-williams`

I then run a query on this name: `http://api.soundcloud.com/users?q=glennon-williams&client_id=XXX` and match the `permalink` to the user name I searched.

Is there a more straightforward / easier way to do this?  What could go wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the resolve endpoint.

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve

Here is the logic in JS:

```
SC.get('/resolve', { url: scurl }, function(resolverr) {
console.log(resolverr);
if(resolverr.kind == 'track')
{console.log(resolverr.user.id)}
else 
{console.log(resolverr.id)}    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/6thxporm/

Without programming:

http://os.bnz-power.com/soursound/#/user/glennon-williams

Comment: Awesome suggestion!  This is the way to go!